# WPF - '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[1].(2)'

Tags: c#, wpf

I am getting the error in the title in the xaml below. On investigating the xaml a little more, I found out that the error relates to using the agent checkbox 'chkAgent' to enable and disable the textbox 'txtAgent' but I can't see why the error is occuring.

Note : The application runs without an error and the textbox enables and disables when I check and uncheck the agent checkbox.

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsAgent, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnableAgent}" Name="chkAgent" TabIndex="2" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=AgentCode}" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkAgent, Path=IsChecked}" Name="txtAgent" TabIndex="4" />
```

Comment: Have you tried using `x:Name` instead of `Name`? Also it is better to use `x:Name`.

Comment: Yep, tried that but the issue still remains.

Comment: Set it to IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsAgent}" and it works fine. Strangely, I can't do the same on a button and have to enable or disable that in the code behind.